# GeckoFX hyperlink with target='_blank' in browser

Tags: c#, window, geckofx

I need a hyperlink with target='_blank' from geckowebbrowser1 to open in geckowebbrowser2 and not in a new window.

```
        private void geckowebbrowser1_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
    {
        geckowebbrowser2.Navigate(e.Uri);

    }
```

but a new window is created anyway :(

Comment: Is this `geckowebbrowser1_CreateWindow` a system event or your own function? Because if it's a system event the CreateWindow name it's explaining what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, you could avoid creation of the new window by setting `Cancel` to false, like this:

```
private void geckowebbrowser1_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    geckowebbrowser2.Navigate(e.Uri);
}
```

If you're interested, here's the part of the source code that handles the creation of a new window and calling the CreateWindow event handler:

```
GeckoWebBrowser browser = parent as GeckoWebBrowser;
if (browser != null)
{
    var e = new GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs(flags);
    browser.OnCreateWindow(e);

    if (e.Cancel)
    {
        cancel = true;
        return null; // When you set cancel to true on your end, the below code for creating a new window won't run
    }

    if (e.WebBrowser != null)
    {
        // set flags
        ((nsIWebBrowserChrome) e.WebBrowser).SetChromeFlagsAttribute(chromeFlags);
        return e.WebBrowser;
    }

    nsIXULWindow xulChild = AppShellService.CreateTopLevelWindow(null, null, chromeFlags, e.InitialWidth, e.InitialHeight);
    return Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIWebBrowserChrome>(xulChild);
}

return null;
```

Comment: thank you, that's what I meant. the new window does not appear

Comment: Good to hear! It's been years since I worked with the Gecko project.